# Colloquial English way of asking question

Tags: colloquial-language

Having gone to market, my friend was asked question that what are the items which has been bought. If I want to ask in colloquial slang.How can i ask?

Answer (score 1):

"What did you get?" But with the first three words said fast to make it "whadjyuh get?" or even "wha'dya get"

Comment: In Essex: "Watcha got there mate?".....   errrrrrgggggh!